# Facebook like infinite scrolling

Tags: extjs

Will it be possible to implement facebook or linked in like infinite scrolling using EXT-JS API. I am aware of infinite grid although my requirement is to scroll panels infinitely just like facebook or linked in allows us.  As of now I am working on EXT version 5. 
Any link/white paper will greatly be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance
Samir

Comment: here: http://xomino.com/2013/03/11/extjs-in-xpages-5-infinite-scroller/

Comment: Please make your question specific with code samples etc - links generally are not acceptable SO answers.

Comment: @unixmiah Thank you for the response. Although the example which you pointed out is for infinite grid. What I need to do is to scroll divs infinitely same like that of facebook. Infinite grid does not allow me to do scroll div contents.

Comment: ahh... http://philipbjorge.github.io/Infinite-Social-Wall/

Comment: Although its the jquery implementation. I was looking for EXT-JS 5 implementation. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`dataview`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View) with a store tied to it to load the initial data in the wall.  Then, in a `controller` add a listener to the `scroll` event and check when the scroll has reached the end.

I previously was creating a reddit app with that exact functionality though it was never completed/fully vetted.  Here is a snippet of the scroll callback, basically I kicked off an ajax request and then load the returned data to the **end** of the current store's data:

```
mainPanelRendered: function () {
        var p = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('yourDataView')[0];
        var s = p.getStore();
        //check on scroll if we've reached the end of the dataview
        p.getTargetEl().on('scroll', function (e, t) {
            var height = p.getTargetEl().getHeight();
            if (height + t.scrollTop >= t.scrollHeight) { //Fire method to load more data to the store.
                p.setLoading(true);
                Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                    callbackKey:'jsonp',
                    url: s.proxy.url,
                    params: {
                        'count': 25,
                        'after': p.after
                    },
                    headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/json;  charset=utf-8', 'Accepts': 'text/json' },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'data.children',
                        successProperty: 'success'
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        p.after = response.data.after;
                        //now that you have more data add it to the store
                        Ext.each(response.data.children, function (article) {
                            var data = article.data;
                            try{
                                s.add({
                                    id: data.id,
                                    domain: data.domain,
                                    subreddit: data.subreddit,
                                    author: data.author,
                                    over_18: data.over_18,
                                    thumbnail: data.thumbnail,
                                    subreddit_id: data.subreddit_id,
                                    downs: data.downs,
                                    ups: data.ups,
                                    permalink: data.permalink,
                                    name: data.name,
                                    url: data.url,
                                    title: data.title,
                                    num_comments: data.num_comments,
                                    score: data.score
                                });
                            } catch (ex) {
                                //do nothing the item already existed
                            }
                            //s.add(item);
                            //newItems[i] = item;
                            //i++;
                        });
                        p.setLoading(false);
                        //p.after = p.response.data.after;
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    },
```

And [here is a link to my not-so-complete app's source](https://github.com/weeksdev/ExtReddit).  Again, it certainly isn't fully vetted but should give you an idea how you could add an infinite scroll.  Checkout the mainPanel in the view and the render event in the controller.

Comment: Thank you so much weeksdev. It's indeed good information that you have provided. Its definitely a good kick start. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @user1845926 Based on your comment you should mark this as answer and decide upvoting it...